# Batch embed SVG markers to geopackage

Tags: qgis, batch, geopackage, svg

I have recently converted my QGIS project with more than 70 layers to a GeoPackage in order to be able to hand the project over to other persons and computers. The project includes over 100 SVG symbols for things as marine buoys, terrain details and so on, and these SVG files are spread out in the QGIS standard SVG folders and in my different folders with self-made SVG images. As the QGIS project file includes relative paths for every SVG that are not part of the QGIS standard library, it is a very time consuming thing to go through every layer and all the SVG paths to get the SVGs to work together with the GeoPackage.

Is there a way to include the SVG data into the GeoPackage as a batch process or similar, instead of spending days with processing every single SVG separately inside QGIS?

Or is there any other way to effectively get all the SVGs moved with the project so that they work on other computers together with the GeoPackage without having to edit each individual path in the layers inside the project?